# Defined formatting within subroutine gives me error that it is undefined?

Tags: function, gfortran, subroutine

I'm a bit puzzled upon receiving this error as I have clearly defined my formatting yet I keep getting the following error:

```
26 |     write(string,100) 'The area of triangle with sides',sidea,', ',sideb,' , and ',sidec,' is', Area(sidea,sideb,sidec)
   |                                                                                                                       
1
Error: FORMAT label 100 at (1) not defined
praclect15#3.f90:29:108:

29 |     write(string,200) 'The area of triangle with sides',sidea,', ',sideb,' , and ',sidec,' is not possible.'
   |                                                                                                            
1
Error: FORMAT label 200 at (1) not defined
```

here is my subroutine:

```
contains

subroutine tri(sidea,sideb,sidec,string) 
implicit none
real,intent(in):: sidea,sideb,sidec
character(len=75),intent(out):: string
if (sidea>0 .and. sideb>0 .and. sidec>0 .and. sidea+sideb>sidec .and. sideb+sidec>sidea .and. sidec+sidea>sideb) then
    write(string,100) 'The area of triangle with sides',sidea,', ',sideb,' , and ',sidec,' is', Area(sidea,sideb,sidec)
    100 format(a,f5.2,a,f5.2,a,5.2,a,f8.2) 
    else
    write(string,200) 'The area of triangle with sides',sidea,', ',sideb,' , and ',sidec,' is not possible.'
    200 format (a,f5.2,a,f5.2,a,5.2,a)
end if
end subroutine tri

real function area(Sa,Sb,Sc)
implicit none
real:: Sa,Sb,Sc,S
S=(Sa+Sb,Sc)/2
area=sqrt(S*(S-Sa)*(S-Sb)*(S-Sa))
end function area
```

What my subroutine is meant to do is calculate the area of the triangle when possible (e.g. when it satisfies the specified conditions of the if statements) using the local function. The only issue I appear to have is that the format is not defined. But I have clearly defined it, so I'm not so sure what the issue is.

thank you.

Comment: Your format statements are not correct: take a look at `a,5.2,a`.

Comment: Also, the line `S=(Sa+Sb,Sc)/2` is not valid.

Comment: ohh okay. looks like I had an issue proofreading my code. Thank you for all your help!